# How to perform join operation on AVRO formatted data in kafka streams using JAVA

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

STREAM-1:

```
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 1, "name": "john", "age": 26, "updated_at": 1525774480752}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 2, "name": "jane", "age": 24, "updated_at": 1525774480784}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 3, "name": "julia", "age": 25, "updated_at": 1525774480827}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 4, "name": "jamie", "age": 22, "updated_at": 1525774480875}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 5, "name": "jenny", "age": 27, "updated_at": 1525774482927}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 6, "name": "kishore", "age": 27, "updated_at": 1525775063908}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 7, "name": "purna", "age": 27, "updated_at": 1525775072006}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 8, "name": "xxx", "age": 10, "updated_at": 1525783464123}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 9, "name": "yyy", "age": 10, "updated_at": 1525783667644}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 10, "name": "zzz", "age": 10, "updated_at": 1525783741814}
```

STREAM-2:

```
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002]: null, {"id": 1, "name": "d", "age": 67}
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002]: null, {"id": 2, "name": "e", "age": 78}
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002]: null, {"id": 12, "name": "d", "age": 67}
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000002]: null, {"id": 21, "name": "e", "age": 78}
```

Now I want to perform JOIN operation on both the streams and want to retrieve rows of stream-1 only that are not present in stream-2. My input streams data was AVRO format

Expected Output :

```
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 3, "name": "julia", "age": 25, "updated_at": 1525774480827}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 4, "name": "jamie", "age": 22, "updated_at": 1525774480875}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 5, "name": "jenny", "age": 27, "updated_at": 1525774482927}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 6, "name": "kishore", "age": 27, "updated_at": 1525775063908}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 7, "name": "purna", "age": 27, "updated_at": 1525775072006}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 8, "name": "xxx", "age": 10, "updated_at": 1525783464123}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 9, "name": "yyy", "age": 10, "updated_at": 1525783667644}
 [KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: null, {"id": 10, "name": "zzz", "age": 10, "updated_at": 1525783741814}
```

So which JOIN operation should I perform and how to achieve my expected output ? Can anyone help me out to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation here: [kafka streams join semantics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics) you could possibly use a **Left Join** and just return null in your value joiner when values from stream2 are set.

Some pseudo code:

```
stream1.leftJoin(stream2, valueJoiner);

valueJoiner = (s1, s2) -> {if (s2 != null) {
      return false
   } else {
     return true;
   } 
};
```

disclaimer: I have not tested this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is in JAVA 7  know but, can you please tell me how to write this in JAVA 8 because I am new to this AVRO formatted data. @Daniel Figueroa